# Differentiability implies continuity proof doubt

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I have a question in one of the steps taken to prove that a differentiable function at a point a is also continuous there.
On Spivak book, the proof is done in the following manner:
Looking at the limit as h approaches zero of the difference f(a+h)-f(a) we say that is equal to the limit as h approaches zero of the product of the secant line slope between points (a,f(a)) and (a+h,f(a+h)) times h. Now, the limit of the quotient exists since f is differentiable by hypothesis at a and the limit as h tends to zero of h exists and equals zero. Hence, the whole limit can be said to equal some real number f’(a) times 0 which as a whole is just 0. Now, this next step is where my doubt is.

Having concluded that the limit as h approaches zero of the difference f(a+h)-f(a) equals 0, it looks like this limit is equal to the difference if the separate limits as h approaches zero of f(a+h) and f(a) exist; so by subtracting by f(a) from both sides, we conclude that the limit of f(a+h) as h approaches zero equals f(a) which I know is equivalent to saying that f is continuous at a. My doubt is why can you say that the limit of the difference is the difference of limits in this case? Don’t you need to verify that the separate limits exist to do that (as it was done similarly to say that whole limit = f’(a) * 0 )?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\lim_{h\to a}\bigl(\alpha(h)-\beta(h)\bigr)$ exists and equals $0$, then it is not necessarily the case that either $\lim_{h\to a}\alpha(h)$ or $\lim_{h\to a}\beta(h)$ exist. For instance, take $\alpha(h)=\beta(h)=\sin(1/h)$ and $a=0$. So you are right to question why Spivak is allowed to do what he does.

The reason that Spivak's method is acceptable is because, with the additional hypothesis that $\beta$ is a constant function, if $\lim_{h\to a}\bigl(\alpha(h)-\beta(h)\bigr)=0$ exists and equals $0$, then this *does* imply that both $\lim_{h\to a}\alpha(h)$ and $\lim_{h\to a}\beta(h)$ exist.

To prove this, suppose that $\beta(h)$ is always equal to some $c\in\mathbb R$. Then, by the definition of $\lim_{h\to a}\bigl(\alpha(h) -c\bigr)=0$, for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that
$$
0<|h-a|<\delta\implies |\alpha(h)-c|<\varepsilon
$$
Now notice that the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of $\lim_{h\to a}\alpha(h)=c$ is exactly the same. Hence, $\lim_{h\to a}\alpha(h)$ exists (and it is trivial that $\lim_{h\to a}\beta(h)$ exists, since $\beta$ is a constant function).

Comment: In fact, if the limit of the difference of the non constant and constant functions was any constant d (not necessarily zero like in here), then the limit of the nonconstant function would also exist and equal the sum of constants right? The key thing is that the limit of the nonconstant will exist given the hypothesis.

Comment: @Alejandro: Yes, that is correct. Even more generally: if $\lim_{h\to a}\bigl(\alpha(h)-\beta(h)\bigr)$ exists and equals $l$, and $\lim_{h\to a}\beta(h)$ exists and equals $m$, then $\lim_{h\to a}\bigl(\left(\alpha(h)-\beta(h)\right)+\beta(h)\bigr)$ exists, i.e. $\lim_{h\to a}\alpha(h)$ exists, and equals $l+m$. By the way, if you want to typeset the mathematical formulae, see [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33179/short-and-helpful-advice-on-using-mathjax-on-the-site) tutorial.

Answer (score 4):

So, Spivak proves that$$\lim_{h\to0}\bigl(f(a+h)-f(a)\bigr)=0$$and your doubt is whether he can jump right away to$$\lim_{h\to0}f(a+h)=f(a).$$Yes, he can. In general, in order to jump from$$\lim_{h\to a}\bigl(\alpha(h)-\beta(h)\bigr)=0\quad\text{to}\quad\lim_{h\to a}\alpha(h)=\lim_{h\to a}\beta(h),$$one must first prove that both limits $\lim_{h\to a}\alpha(h)$ and $\lim_{h\to a}\beta(h)$ exist. But not when one of the functions is constant (which is the case here). In fact,$$\lim_{h\to a}\bigl(\alpha(h)-k\bigr)=\left(\lim_{h\to a}\alpha(h)\right)-k$$as long as *any* of the limits mentioned here exists.